How can i set the color of the status bar in a .net android app?
I'm trying to change the color of an android app that uses avalonia for UI.
Here is my MainActivity:
public class MainActivity : AvaloniaMainActivity<App>
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View decorView = Window.DecorView;
        var uiOptions = decorView.WindowSystemUiVisibility;
        var newuioptions = uiOptions;
        newuioptions |=  SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable |  SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen;
        decorView.SystemUiFlags = newuioptions;
        Window.SetStatusBarColor(Color.Orange);
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected override AppBuilder CustomizeAppBuilder(AppBuilder builder)
    {
        return base.CustomizeAppBuilder(builder)
            .WithInterFont()
            .UseReactiveUI();
    }
}

The status bar remains unchanged no matter what I do. What am I missing and how can I change the android status bar?

Why don't you try setting color from styles.xml by defining a theme and use it in MainActivity. By calling it in OnCreate function like SetTheme(Resource.Style.MyTheme);

@BobSmith, That doesent work either. Ive discovered there is nothing wrong with the code because when i extend AppCompatActvity instead of AvaloniaMainActivity, it works well. Must be an issue with avalonia

There seems to be a limitation with directly setting the status bar color through code in Avalonia.NET for Android. While AppCompatActivity allows native access to these functionalities, Avalonia might require a different approach.

Seems so @BobSmith. I will create an issue in their repository so we can discover a solution!

Good idea, do post the issue link here by editing your question, So that future readers can also look into it and get help from your findings.

Found a fix. Override OnWindowFocusChanged instead of OnCreate. The view being created by avalonia was interfering with it
 public override void OnWindowFocusChanged(bool hasFocus)
    {  
        View decorView = Window.DecorView;
        var uiOptions = decorView.WindowSystemUiVisibility;
        var newuioptions = uiOptions;
        newuioptions |=  SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable |  SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen;
        decorView.SystemUiFlags = newuioptions;
        Window.SetStatusBarColor(Color.Transparent);
        base.OnWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }


